# Selenium WebDriver Second click not working

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

I am preforming making clicks by position, When I move to position and make click.
The first click working fine, but the other there is no reaction.

My main goal: I have list with (x,y) were I need to click

**Code**

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.MoveByOffset(BlocX + 12, BlocY + 12);
 action.Click();//only this is working
 action.Perform();
 action.Release();

 action.MoveByOffset(BlocX + 36, BlocY + 12);
 action.Click();
 action.Perform();
 action.Release();

 action.MoveByOffset(BlocX + 60, BlocY + 12);
 action.Click();
 action.Perform();
 action.Release();
```

What am I missing in this code, how do I preform all the clicks?

I tried to make perform in the end this is not working too

This is code

```
  Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
  action.MoveByOffset(BlocX + 12, BlocY + 12);
  action.Click();
  action.Release();
  action.MoveByOffset(BlocX + 36, BlocY + 12);
  action.Click();
  action.Release();
  action.MoveByOffset(BlocX + 60, BlocY + 12);
  action.Click();

  action.Perform();
```

This make more that one click only in this case when i don't move mouse position again

```
  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
  builder.MoveByOffset(BlocX + 12, BlocY + 12).Click();
  builder.Click();
  builder.Click();
  builder.Click();
  builder.Perform();
```

Any one have idea how to do all clicks on all positions?

Comment: Why are you using the `Actions` why cannot you find the element on the page?

Comment: this is area element,clicks dont work with it

Comment: are you sure that each positions are independent? I mean when it clicks the first one the locations of others may be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building all the sequential actions and then performing it. Also call `new` on `Actions` class every time you have to click because, according to your code while performing the second click, the mouse pointer would be at position `BlocX + 12`. So your second click is happening at `BlockX + 12 + BlockX + 36`.

```
// click 1
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveByOffset(BlocX + 12, BlocY + 12).click().build().perform();

// click 2
actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveByOffset(BlocX + 36, BlocY + 12).click().build().perform();

// click 3
actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveByOffset(BlocX + 60, BlocY + 12).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: It make first click and others no reaction,the others have another position +60 and +84

Comment: i found it .after first click it have to be  actions.MoveByOffset(24, 0).Click().Build().Perform();,...it will move +24px from last position